# In Outlook 2010, how do I disable the search box at the bottom of a message?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Whenever I open a message in Outlook 2010 I have the following bar at the bottom:

[image]

How can I turn this off?  I've search through help and everything and it's entirely unclear.  I am running on Windows Server 2008 in case that makes any kind of difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course right after I post the question I find the answer.  Apparently it's called the Outlook Social Connector.

You can follow these instructions to uninstall the component:

http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/pages/help-with-updating-the-outlook-social-connector-in-the-outlook-2010-beta.aspx

Comment: Good one, I also disabled it.